# A question on Ito integral

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus

Let $W$ be a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion and $0<T<+\infty$. Then
$$\lim_{\beta\to+\infty}\sup_{0\le t\le T}|e^{-\beta t}\int_0^te^{\beta s}\mathrm{d}W_s|=0\quad \text{a.s.}$$

Could anyone give some hints or proofs?

Comment: If I have done it correctly, stochastic integration by parts gives $$e^{-\beta t} \int_0^t e^{\beta t}\,dW_s = W_t - \int_0^t W_s \beta e^{-\beta(t-s)}\,ds$$ which seems to show this is not true, as the second term on the right side goes to 0 as $\beta \to \infty$.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge - that was my initial reaction too. However the integrand on the RHS is not bounded by an integrable function as $\beta \to \infty$ ($\beta e^{-\beta t} \ge \beta(1 - \beta t) \ge \beta/2$ for $t \le 1/2\beta$, in particular any (uniform in $\beta$) upper bound $g$ satisfies $g(x) \ge 1/4x$). On the other hand Ito isometry yields
$$
E\left[ \left( e^{-\beta t} \int_0^t e^{\beta s} dW_s \right)^2 \right] = \frac{1}{2\beta}(1 - e^{-2\beta t} ) \to 0
$$
as $\beta \to \infty$. Also I did a quick simulation in R. I think the OP's statement is correct.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: This is an Orenstein-Uhlenbeck process with high damping (solution to $dX_t=-\beta X_t dt+dW_t$, starting at 0). Of course it goes to $0$ as $\beta\to\infty$....

Answer (score 2):

As Nate Eldredge says, integration by parts implies 
$$
e^{ - \beta t } \int_0^t e^{ \beta s } dW_s = W_t - \beta \int_0^t e^{ - \beta ( t - s ) } W_s ds \\
= \beta \int_0^t e^{ - \beta ( t - s ) } ( W_t - W_s ) ds + e^{ -\beta t }W_t.
$$
The supremum of the two terms above tend to zero. The second one, for example, follows because the maximum of the function $ t \mapsto e^{-\beta t } t$ is attained at $\beta^{-1}$, and $\sup_{t \in (0,T )} t^{-1}|W_t|$ is in $L^1$. The first term converges uniformly to zero from the fact that brownian motion is uniformly Holder of order $\alpha\in(0,1/2)$ and because 
$$
\lim_{ \beta \to \infty }\sup_{ t \in (0,T) } \beta \int_0^te^ss^\alpha ds = 0.
$$ 
The last fact can be proved from the standard integration by parts theorem.